# Create multiple services in a plugin in lagom

Tags: lagom

I want to be able to make multiple services(for each aggregate) in a single plugin. But lagom does not allow this. Example, I have 2 aggregates - EmailThread and EmailMessage.

```
EmailThreadAggregate{

createEmailThread(emailMessageId);

closeEmailThread();

//many other commands
}

EmailMessageAggregate{

createEmailMessage(EmailMessageDetails emailMessageDetails);

markEmailMessageDeliverySuccess();

markEmailMessageDeliveryFailure();

//many more commands
}
```

Both have separate commands and life-cycle, but both are closely related.

Hence, I would want to create the above 2 aggregates and its 2 services, EmailThreadService and EmailMessageService in the same plugin. Can anyone help me with why lagom does not allow this?

Comment: Lagom does allow this. What makes you believe it does not?

Comment: @TimMoore
When I tried to bind 2 services like:         

`bindService(EmailThreadService.class, EmailThreadServiceImpl.class);         bindService(EmailMessageService.class, EmailMessageServiceImpl.class); `
in one Module and start the plugin using the run command it throws Exception

Comment: You can use multiple types of persistent entities with a single service.

Comment: @TimMoore So, In my case I would have code of both EmailThread and EmailMessage   in a single service. Is this correct from the perspective of OOPs? Wouldn't it be better to create 2 separate services for them?

Comment: @TimMoore in case of creating a single service are we not breaking the Single Responsibility. Also is Service in Lagom is equal to one Microservice ???? From my perspective for having the Single Responsibility of a Service in place Lagom should allow for multiple Services in one Plugin  and Plugin is Synonym to Microservice ......

Comment: Yes, a service in Lagom is equivalent to a microservice as a unit of deployment. The service interface represents the interface into that service. You are free to split up the internal implementation of persistent entities into multiple classes as you see fit.

Comment: I have the exact same issue. With User and Role. They are so closely related that I don't want to split them into their own microservices. So I ended up with a rather big service class covering both Entities. Permissions somehow are close as well, but I splitted them up into their own microservice. Now I'm thinking about migrating roles into their own service as well. But they will never be used anywhere without a User. So I don't like it both ways. Having two ServiceCall Interfaces and Implemenations in one Microservice would feel nicer.